# Unable to read single character in Java

Tags: java

I wrote this code based on an example I found:

```
do {
    System.out.print("¿What kind of envelope do you want? (A)Mini B)Midi C)Maxi): ");
    cadena = sc.next();
    tipo = cadena.charAt(0);
    tipo=Character.toUpperCase(tipo);
} while (tipo != 'A' || tipo != 'B' || tipo != 'C');
```

But it keeps asking me constantly the kind of envelope instead of registering my choice.
What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Think about your conditional.  Imagine all possible scenarios and work out what your conditional is saying.

Answer (score 2):

```
tipo != 'A' || tipo != 'B' || tipo != 'C'
```

If the input is A OR B OR C - the condition would still return true.
And it would continue to loop cause it would not match the other two combinations.

```
!(tipo == 'A' || tipo == 'B' || tipo == 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `||` operators to `&&`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I can't even build the project with that operators

Comment: Yep.  Too early in the morning...  (For a Saturday)

Comment: @user1043134 -- Try it again -- I typed `%%` when I meant `&&`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `!tipos.equals('A')` instead of `!=`

Comment: `tipos` is of type `char` (as inferred by the call to `Character.toUpperCase(tipo)`). Chars are primitives, and as such `!=` is correct. Even if it was declared as a `Character`, autoboxing would mean the comparison still worked correctly